# Update в MySql в очереди Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, очередь

Задача стоит в инкременте счетчика посещения страниц без задержек, хочу использовать для этого очередь, но не пойму как это можно реализовать

Answer (score 1):

Выберите сервис очередей, с которым будете работать. Установите, настройте его. Далее можно воспользоваться [инструкцией](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/queues).